# Set of smooth curves on the Hilbert scheme is open. H

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hilbert-schemes, smoothness

Let $H = Hilb_{d,g,r}$ be the Hilbert scheme of genus $g$ curves of degree $d$ in proyective space $\mathbb{P}^r$, over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Is it true that the set of points of $H$ consisting of smooth curves is open in $H$?
If so, how do I see this?

Edit: added the hypothesis that the base field is algebraically closed.

Comment: Please look up `generic smoothness' and see how it can be applied.